# MSCHart X-axis values showing error

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I havs an MSChart which takes in a series of data elements

```
foreach(Int16 element in data)
{
    this.view.chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY((double)i/100, (double) element/41);
}
this.view.chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Mimimum=0;
this.view.chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
this.view.chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0,10);
this.view.chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 10;
```

This views the the chart in 10 second frames, so this should go from 0 - 10, then 10 to 20, etc.
Now the strange thing is, when I first launch the chart, it correctly shows the data within the time frame 0 to 10. BUT when I fist click to scroll forward to the next 10 second frame, it shows 9.994 to 19.994, then 19.994 to 29.994.

Now, if I scroll all the way back to the start (i.e. 0 top 10) and then scroll forward again it WORKS! goes from 0 - 10, 10 - 20, 20 - 30 but when I reach the end of my chart ot goes back into the annoying double value (e.g. 69.994) :S

I really cant figure out why this is happening, could anyone help me please

PS. This is a line chart not a bar chart

Comment: Dont know if will help, but try to use `yourSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32`

Comment: Tried that but same thing still occurs and thank you also for helping :) I also tried to use the RoundAxisValue() and still no difference :(

Comment: Can you provide working code snippet, cause ChartAreas[0] doesn't have Minimum field

Comment: Hi I have updated the code now should work and thank you so much for your time I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Cant reproduce yor problem, but try no to cast (i/100) to `double`

Comment: I need that cast in order to plot exact data positions :( if I remove it the display starts to go too shart and alot of data disapprears. I think to reproduce this you would need and array of about 19000 elements or so, im sure with a small array the problem would not be visible.

Comment: I think I found your problem use `(double)(i/100)` instead `(double)i/100`

Comment: Thank does fix the annoying X-axis values but then it has disturbed my data display :S dunno why that is, one thing gets fixed and another breaks, typical isnt it :)

Comment: than you can use `LabelStyle.Format` for displaying labels. `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}";`

Comment: Hi Stecya Its me youngCoder, i dont have a proper account on this but I used your format and its worked Perfectly! so I wanted to say thank you very much for all you help :) I really appreciate it alot!

Comment: @Stecya: Can you post your comments as an answer so we can get this question off the Unanswered page?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

than you can use `LabelStyle.Format` for displaying labels.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}";
```